# Angular2 parametr base Routing Error as Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular2-routing

Here i'm using Angular2 Lazy Loading parameter based Routing Plase help why im Getting  `Error: Cannot match any routes: 'EditById/1113'`
Here i'm passing this Id from Table Like

```
     <tr *ngFor="let emp of employee">
    <td><a href="#" (click)="GetById($event,emp)">{{emp.EmpName}}</a></td>
 GetById(e, emp) {
        debugger;
        this.id = emp.Emp_Id;
        this._router.navigate(['/EditById/' + this.id])
    }
```

This  is My MainRoute.ts

```
export const ApplicationRoutes:Routes= [
    { path: 'EditById/:id', loadChildren: '../modules/employee/editemployeebyidmdule#EitEmployeeModule' },
```

**EmployeeRoute.ts**

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router"
import { EditEmployeeByIdComponent } from "../components/employeecomponent/editemployeebyidcomponent"
export const EmployeeRoute=[
    { path: 'id', component: EditEmployeeByIdComponent}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be,

```
this._router.navigate(['EditById', this.id])
```

Comment: Even though Error as Cannot match any routes: 'EditById/1108'

Comment: Is their we need anything from ngOnInit